# Need Developer Trial License

Tags: licensing

I am interested in learning Sitecore and I saw many posts talking about 60 days developer license but I am unable to get one as I am looking for a full developer license but not front-end license as shown in the below link.
https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/developer-trial

I have even mailed sitecore support and there is no response.

Am I missing something or please help me in applying the developer license. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with this front-end license? I believe this should work

Comment: Applied but yet to get any license file. Does this fron-end JSS license allow trial of Experience Manager and Experience Platform?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the 60 day developer trial license is no longer available, and the only trial that is now available is the front-end JSS trial you have mentioned. Previous details about the developer trial license have also been removed from this question on [how to get started learning Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/posts/1738/revisions).

We seem to have regressed on options for new developers and your only option now to learn Sitecore is to use either a partner license or a development license for the customer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If i get partner license then can i use it in personal device? If not then I am afraid I might need to go to office for using the license as I am only allocated a desktop. This isn't possible due to covid -19.

Comment: You would need to check the terms of the license or confirm with your partner rep. Generally, if it is for learning purposes I have taken the view that the partner license on a personal device is fine.